# If we have sets $A,B$ such that there are no injective functions $A \to B$, can we find an injective function $B \to A$?

Tags: set-theory

The question is in the title. I've done some reading and seen that assuming AC, existence of such a function is guaranteed since the cardinals are well-ordered. Can we explicitly construct such a function?

Comment: What do you mean by "explicitly construct"?  AC is non-constructive $B\xrightarrow{(WO)}\beta\hookrightarrow\alpha\xrightarrow{(WO)}A$ where the two (WO) may or may not satisfy your definition of "explicitly construct".

Comment: Are you thinking of having the proof of the statement "there are no injective functions $A \to B$" as part of your input available for doing an explicit construction? That proof might be the two $WO$ maps and a proof that $\beta \lt \alpha$ so you have pieces you can glue together into an explicit function.

Comment: Aah, so you essentially need the well-ordering maps to be explicit. I was hoping for a solution along the lines of @AHusain's comment but in light of other comments that seems like far more work than I envisioned. Thanks for this!